# How can CircleCI build successfully with no tests?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I have some repos purely for Dockerfiles.  I use CircleCI to build and publish the images on commit.  There are no tests but that makes Circle angry: the build fails. Is there a directive in circle.yml to calm it down, i.e. instruct it not to look for tests?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see explicit support for that in [the documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/manually/). But you can override the default test command to be a command that always passes. In circle.yml:

```
test:
  override:
    - /bin/true
```

(Specifying the full path to `true` is necessary to prevent "true" from being parsed as a Boolean.)